# Display UIViewController as Popup in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, popup, uialertview

*Since there is no complete, definitive answer to this common recurring question, I'll ask and answer it here.*

Often we need to present a `UIViewController` such that it doesn't cover full screen, as in the picture below.

[image]

Apple provides several similar `UIViewController`, such as `UIAlertView`, Twitter or Facebook share view controller, etc..

**How can we achieve this effect for a custom controller?**

Comment: Please comment why you have down vote so that I can improve.

Comment: I would recommend you to use [STPopup](http://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup) Use it just like UINavigationController.

Comment: I found this pod is good: https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**NOTE : This solution is broken in iOS 8. I will post new solution ASAP.**

I am going to answer here using storyboard but it is also possible without storyboard.

1. **Init:** Create two `UIViewController` in storyboard.

   - lets say `FirstViewController` which is normal and `SecondViewController` which will be the popup.
2. **Modal Segue:** Put `UIButton` in FirstViewController and create a segue on this `UIButton` to `SecondViewController` as modal segue.
3. **Make Transparent:** Now select `UIView` (`UIView` Which is created by default with `UIViewController`) of `SecondViewController` and change its background color to clear color.
4. **Make background Dim:** Add an `UIImageView` in `SecondViewController` which covers whole screen and sets its image to some dimmed semi transparent image. You can get a sample from here : [`UIAlertView` Background Image](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_QLwms0mVa4w/S_FsI-DMghI/AAAAAAAAAp8/-4Uwv-yDhVY/behind_alert_view.png?imgmax=800)
5. **Display Design:** Now add an `UIView` and make any kind of design you want to show. Here is a screenshot of my storyboard
   [image: storyboard]

   - Here I have add segue on login button which open `SecondViewController` as popup to ask username and password
6. **Important:** Now that main step. We want that `SecondViewController` doesn't hide FirstViewController completely. We have set clear color but this is not enough. By default it adds black behind model presentation so we have to add one line of code in viewDidLoad of `FirstViewController`. You can add it at another place also but it should run before segue.

   `[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];`
7. **Dismiss:** When to dismiss depends on your use case. This is a modal presentation so to dismiss we do what we do for modal presentation:

   `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];`

Thats all.....

Any kind of suggestion and comment are welcome.

**Demo :**
You can get demo source project from Here : [Popup Demo](https://github.com/chinatndave/popupDemo)

**NEW** : Someone have done very nice job on this concept : [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController)
**New** : I found one more code to get this kind of function : [KLCPopup](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup)

---

> **iOS 8 Update** : I made this method to work with both iOS 7 and iOS 8

```
+ (void)setPresentationStyleForSelfController:(UIViewController *)selfController presentingController:(UIViewController *)presentingController
{
    if (iOSVersion >= 8.0)
    {
        presentingController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
        presentingController.definesPresentationContext = YES;

        [presentingController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    }
    else
    {
        [selfController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
        [selfController.navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    }
}
```

---

Can use this method inside prepareForSegue deligate like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    PopUpViewController *popup = segue.destinationViewController;
    [self setPresentationStyleForSelfController:self presentingController:popup]
}
```

Comment: Setting `[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];` seems to be breaking the modal transition animation (`UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve` for example) when presenting second view controller so it is just popping up without animation. Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: @cevitcejbo Thanks to have a look. on segue if we set transition property to any that is is giving animation but only when dismiss not on show. Till I dont know how to solve it. I edit my answer when I find. If u find that plese inform me.

Comment: @CRDave, as you suggested above, `[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];` does not work alone. One has to use `[self.navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];` also as depicted from your demo project.

Comment: @Kailash Yes you are right if one have used navigationController  than it is required. I have write it here : https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/popupDemo/issues/1. Thanks to add it here.

Comment: How to change the rect of the pop up?

Comment: In my example you can change rect in stryboard.

Comment: With ios 8 after present the popup, the background of the back view became black.

Comment: @lee Read first line of Answer NOTE.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just did this on iOS 7 and added this as the favourite question, then now go back to report without read the update of yours.

Comment: For the iOS 8 problem you can find the solution here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18661

Comment: @Shiim Thank to comment here. I have already tried that solution but it has some problem with UINavigationController thats why I have not posted it here.

Comment: I think there should be a clearer answer on building this as it's not working properly on iOS8. raywenderlich tutorial was working and it also broke somehow. This is too different for iOS7 vs iOS8.

Comment: How we can achieve this same functionality if there is no segue, i.e. If code is created programatically

Comment: This trick has nothing to do with segue. segue is used just to simplify things. Main this is that setPresentationStyleForSelfController method should be called before present operation.

Answer (score 52):

## Modal Popups in Interface Builder (Storyboards)

### Step 1

On the ViewController you want as your modal popup, make the background color of the root UIView clear.
[image: Set Clear Color on root view]
Tip: Do not use the root UIView as your popup. Add a new UIView that is smaller to be your popup.

### Step 2

Create a Segue to the ViewController that has your popup. Select "Present Modally".
[image: Segue]

## Two Methods To Create Popup From Here

### Method One - Using the Segue

Select the Segue and change Presentation to "Over Current Context":
[image: Over Current Context]

### Method Two - Using the View Controller

Select the ViewController Scene that is your popup. In Attributes Inspector, under View Controller section, set Presentation to "Over Current Context":
[image: ViewController]

Either method will work. That should do it!

[image: Finished Product]

Comment: Here is a bit more help if i can:

Create a viewcontroller class in your code somewhere like MyDialog : UIViewController. Set it as the customclass of the new viewcontroller in the storyboard. Put buttons etc. and connect them into your code using Control + Drag. Call dismiss(animated, completion) on button click.

Comment: This is great.. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can do this in Interface Builder.

- For the view you wish to present modally set its outermost view background to transparent
- Control + click and drag from the host view controller to the modal view controller
- Select present modally
- Click on the newly created segue and in the Attribute Inspector (on the right) set "Presentation" to "Over Current Context"

Answer (score 10):

Feel free to use my form sheet controller [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController)for iPhone, in example project there are many examples on how to present modal view controller which will not cover full window and has many presentation/transition styles.

You can also try newest version of MZFormSheetController which is called [MZFormSheetPresentationController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController) and have a lot of more features.

Comment: this form sheet controller looks GREAT, only issue is when I present full screen modal view controller and then dismiss it, the Form sheet controller will become full screen as well. please help

Comment: no need found this handy code of yours ;) 

// To present
MZFormSheetController *formSheet = [[MZFormSheetController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];
        [formSheet presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];

// To Dismiss     
MZFormSheetController *controller = self.navigationController.formSheetController;
    [controller dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score 2):

You can use EzPopup (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup), it is a Swift pod and very easy to use:

```
// init YourViewController
let contentVC = ...

// Init popup view controller with content is your content view controller
let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: contentVC, popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

// show it by call present(_ , animated:) method from a current UIViewController
present(popupVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imao put UIImageView on background is not the best idea . In my case  i added on controller view other 2 views . First view has `[UIColor clearColor]` on background, second - color which u want to be transparent (grey in my case).Note that order is important.Then for second view set alpha 0.5(alpha >=0 <=1).Added  this to lines in `prepareForSegue`

```
infoVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
infoVC.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

And thats all.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

To add an overlay, or the popup view
You can also use the **Container View** with which you get a free View Controller ( you get the Container View from the usual object palette/library)

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Have a View (ViewForContainer in the pic) that holds this Container View, to dim it when the contents of Container View are displayed. Connect the outlet inside the first View Controller
2. Hide this View when 1st VC loads
3. Unhide  when Button is clicked
   [image]
4. To dim this View when the Container View content is displayed, set the Views Background to Black and opacity to 30%

[image]

You will get this effect when you click on the Button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to add any other subview to the view controller.
First set the status bar to None for the ViewController which you want to add as subview so that you can resize to whatever you want. Then create a button in Present View controller and a method for button click. In the method:

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {
    SubView *sub = [[SubView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView" bundle:nil];
    sub.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, sub.view.frame.size.width, sub.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:sub.view];
}
```

Hope this helps, feel free to ask if any queries...

Comment: Here is SubView is a UIViewController with xib interface, not a sub view

Comment: OK I was not aware with this way. Thanks.