# Popup View when clicked MapView annotation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, annotations, popup, mkmapview

I manage to make the annotation clickable using this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
   NSLog(@"touch");
}
```

I would like for a small popup view with 3 buttons and the title of the annotation to appear when the annotation is clicked.

Comment: What you're talking about is a "callout" if you look yo how to make custom callouts you'll find lots of questions and answers about how to do that.

Comment: no I don't want a "callout", I want a popup view to appear when the annotation is pressed something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone

Comment: oh, you just want to make a view and add it to the main view then. Seems simple, what have you tried?

Comment: I try it with two uiviewcontrollers but didn't work, I will try with a view inside the mail view so when I pressed the annotation it will make it visible.

Comment: @Craig thanks it worked with two views, would you like to respond so I can check your answer as correct? also do you know who to get the annotation title on a uilabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view. Then find the mapview's parent and add this new view as a subview of that.