# iOS make popup with table view

Tags: ios, popup, radiobuttonlist

Is there any elegant way to make a popup contains tableView
I could add table view as a subView but it isn't really what  I am looking for.
I have tried to Download third party libraries (from gitHub but all I found were broken links).
I don't want to create a brand new View and use it as navigation since it should be popup.

I think adding a subview with a table view inside of it would solve the solution but I am not sure if it is the best way since I saw some third party code, that solves the issue.
Could anyone please to suggest what is the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: It is better to post some code you've tried before asking for help.

Comment: You need a new view controller. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16230700/335858) for some details that may be relevant.

Comment: @NikosM. I didn't try code , I tried to find a popup window on iOS and I found some 3rd party but they aren't available for downloading so I asked here. also I hoped i could do so with no new controller

Comment: try this: https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView it has a tableview, so you can add on it anything you want. And it is opensource

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the question you linked uses story board , and I don't use interface-buider at all.

Comment: @NikosM. unfortunately I can't open this link :(

Comment: https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView hard to believe that github is not loading.

Comment: @NikosM. yes pretty much just now it did , I guess i will try it first

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."
I didn't ask for code I just asked for optimal solution.