# Show UITableViewController as a popup, Show Detail also in popup

Tags: ios, popup, uitableview

I know how to show a `UIView` in popup, but it can not use `UINavigationController` inside `UIView` show i can show another view when i click a button, That why i thought i should show a `UITableViewController` in a popup, i would like to know how to show a `UITableViewController` so that when i click on any cell it should go to detail page in the same popup window. I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16230701/1997951)
but its not going to detail page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you not to reinvent the wheel, and use one of many useful (and tested) libraries for that. For example, extracted from a quick search on GitHub:

- https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAModalPanel
- https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController