# Adding an animated, modal popup view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiviewcontroller, swift

I'd like to create a view that appears scrolling in from the bottom (on iPad) and sits centered, modally over the currently open view, something like this ...

[image]

What would be the straightforward (and recommended) way to do this when developing apps for iOS7 and up? Is it a matter of simply instantiating the view controller class and adding it as a child or are there any better methods to do this, that include automatically managed modality and animation (like for example when adding an UIPopoverViewController)?

Comment: UIPopoverController. Or WYPopoverController (https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) with support of both iPhone/iPad. Note also, starting from iOS 8 UIPopoverController also available on iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the links! What would be the recommended way to create a popup view without an arrow? I've read that passing 0/nil as permittedArrowDirections is not officially supported?

Comment: WYPopoverController has an option WYPopoverArrowDirectionNone

Comment: Ok, but I can't really make use of WYPopoverController currently as I code in Swift and adding ObjC classes requires bridging which is still a bit of a hurdle for an iOS beginner like me.

Comment: you may found something helpful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone