# Display UIViewController as Popup without seguge

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I used code from this question [Display UIViewController as Popup in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone) it is working fine but I don't want to use segue or I can say I can't use segue because all the code is created programmatically, so I cant set segue on button.

I used this code but it didn't work

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *newVC = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    [ViewController setPresentationStyleForSelfController:self presentingController:newVC];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];

}
```

**Edit 1:**
View after popup

[image]

Comment: When you say popup, do you mean popover or modal?

Comment: Do you have any log message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if this VC `self.navigationController` is not nil. and i think you want to `presentViewController:` not `pushViewController:`...

Comment: This is a comment, there is no solution to the question here so it's not an answer.