# Programmatically showing another UIViewController as popup in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, popup

I have main dashboard (`UITableViewController`)  and once i sign in i need to show this page with a welcome message which am showing using a `UIViewController`.

How can i show this popup from my `ViewDidAppear()` method ?

Am using following code and its not working

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popup"];
        [popupObj setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    }
```

please help me..

i saw couple of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone) links

### Update

When i change my code to this one

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popup"];
   // [popupObj setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    popupObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    popupObj.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:popupObj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now i can see my `UIViewController` coming as popup but now `UIViewController`
coming as full screen view.

But i need only this `frame (320 , 320)`

Comment: The answer to your linked question provides plenty of code, did you try implementing it all or are those two lines the only thing you tried?

Comment: yes tried everything related to this

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all relevant code? And also include a description of what you expected it to do vs what it actually did.

Comment: Where your code to present viewcontroller?

Comment: updating question now

Comment: You can add your view of view controller as a subView of present view controller or window .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popup"];
popupObj.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 168);
[self.view addSubview:popupObj.view];
[self addChildViewController:popupObj];
```

You can add UIViewController as subview and set it's frame so it will look like popup.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: it should work, Is changing in frame does not effect on x, y only or not even width and height of it?

Answer (score 1):

I have two way,maybe not good, but work at most of time.

First,when the second view controller appear, show a screen shot of the first view  controller. like this:

```
- (void)setBackGround {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self.presentingViewController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id)(image.CGImage);
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!_isShown) {
        _isShown = YES;
        [self setBackGround];
    }
}
```

Do't forget set "_isShown = NO" when init.

Second: you can only init a view, and show it on a view controller with animation. code at ：http://blog.moemiku.com/?p=101

I have update a example on the blog.  [Direct download url](http://blog.moemiku.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/PopupViewExample.zip)
[image: the gif]

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates the view controller and sets its presentation style, but doesn't actually present it. For that to happen you need this line after the two you have right now:

```
[self presentViewController:popupObj animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set navigation controller on your rootviewcontroller :

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {  
      popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popup"];
      [self.navigationController presentViewController:popupObj animated:YES completion:nil];

  }
```

Or

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {  
     popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popup"];
        [self.view addSubview:popupObj.view];
  }
```