# How to handle Button click event of custom view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls

I want to do this below concept in my project:

I just created one small custom popup using `UIViewController`, this **custom** **popup** containing one message label and two button, one is "OK" and another one is "Cancel". This **custom** **popup** coding doing in **appdelegate**. Now when I want to open this popup, I just called this **appdelegate** popup method in from **viewcontroller** when I need to open this alert.

Now the problem is, I want to perform different-different functionality on "OK" button of "Custom alert" Popup. So please help to how to I managed this "Ok" Button click event from Individual ViewController.

Comment: [take a look at this](https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView)

Comment: I suggest you to look on cocoacontrols.com as there are plenty of custom alert boxes available. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=alert

Comment: Can you put some code how do you created this alert or the entire method of the cutom button

Comment: As a good practice you should have a dedicated class to handle that. Anyway if you really want to do it from scratch you are after showing modally a dialog. For starters check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below method in a Utility class and call it from your view controller like

```
[Utility showAlertWithTitle:@"ABC" msg:@"msg" vc:self positiveHandler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
  // Do here when ok is pressed
} negativeHandler:nil]; //pass nil when cancel is pressed
```

ObjC

```
+ (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title msg:(NSString *)msg vc:(UIViewController *)vc positiveHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(UIAlertAction *action))positiveHandler negativeHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(UIAlertAction *action))negativeHandler {
  UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

  UIAlertAction *positiveAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:positiveHandler];
  [alertController addAction:positiveAction];

  UIAlertAction *negativeAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:negativeHandler];
  [alertController addAction:negativeAction];

  //show alert
  [vc presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Swift

```
 // Shows alert with yes no button
 static func showAlert(title: String, msg: String, vc: UIViewController, positiveActionHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)?, negativeActionHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)?) {
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
 let positiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .destructive, handler: positiveActionHandler)
 alertController.addAction(positiveAction)

 let negativeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: negativeActionHandler)
 alertController.addAction(negativeAction)
 vc.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```