# Dim superviewcontroller but not child view controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface, mkmapview, childviewcontroller

Is it possible to dim the super viewController but not any of its childViewControllers. For example, dim my map view but not the tableviewController that is its childViewController.

[image]

PopoverViewControllers wont work because I'm on iPhone only. What is my best solution to this problem?

Comment: Add a view on superviewcontroller with transparent background.

Comment: You can use popover view controller in iPhone same as iPad from IOS8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view(e.g. blackMaskView) above mapView with:

```
self.mapview.insertSubview(blackMaskView, aboveSubview: self.mapview)
```

and then add a blur effect to blackMaskView as follows:

```
func createBlurView() {

    // Blur Background

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)

    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.blackMaskView.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Use blackMaskView.isHidden = true, to finally hide the blurred view.
Please mark the answer correct if you find it useful.