# iOS - UIViewController as Popup with dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a Popup-View which contains two labels, a tableview and button. I created a ViewController as in [Display UIViewController as Popup in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230700/display-uiviewcontroller-as-popup-in-iphone) described.

My special requirement is now, that the tableview is not necessary in all cases, so I tried to hide it and expected a reduced height of the Popup-View. But I always get the same height. I also tried to use a UIStackView, but the height of the view wasn't changed in case of hiding the tableview.

I also need to have the view in center of the display in both cases of height.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEluk.png)

```
@interface AuthorizationMessageViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *messageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titelLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *okButton;
- (IBAction)okButtonTouchUp:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation AuthorizationMessageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.messageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.messageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.messageView.backgroundColor = COLOR_BACKGROUND_WHITE;
    self.messageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = COLOR_BACKGROUND_WHITE;

    self.titelLabel.text = WHLocalizedString(@"EventHeaderAuthorization", nil);

    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setupView
{
    NSString *ns_messageText;

    ns_messageText = @"test";

    if (YES)
    {
        ns_messageText = @"Hide"
        [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        ns_messageText = @"No Hide"
        [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
    }

    self.detailsLabel.text = ns_messageText;
    self.detailsLabel.textColor = COLOR_TEXT_GREY_KEY;
    self.detailsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.detailsLabel sizeToFit];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 7;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 21;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];

    UILabel *weekDayLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    weekDayLabel.text = @"weekday";
    weekDayLabel.textColor = COLOR_TEXT_GREY_KEY;
    weekDayLabel.font = FONT_LIGHT_SIZE_15;

    UILabel *testLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    testLabel = @"testLabel"
    testLabel = COLOR_TEXT_GREY_KEY;
    testLabel = FONT_LIGHT_SIZE_15;

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

I hope that someone has a solution or an idea for that.

Comment: provide trial code.

Comment: try this `tableView.isHidden = true` and `tableView.frame = CGRect.zero` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following UI

[image]

a centered `UIView` that contains a `UIButton` and `UITableView` , you need to hook height constraint of the table and do this inside the popup if you want to hide it

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightTblCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

//

```
self.heightTblCon.constant = show ? 300 : 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

BTW i changed color of background view for clarification purposes that should be transparent for modals

Comment: That solution helps me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `sizeToFit()` on Popup-View after hiding the tableView:

```
popupView.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Adjust the Height of your view using the `NSLayoutConstraint`. Create an outlet for the same and manage height programatically. For example:

```
 myConstraintOutlet.constant = 10
 myTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669554/how-to-update-the-constant-height-constraint-of-a-uiview-programatically) is the link for further assistant.

Regarding your second query to have the pop up always in centre you can either do it using `Autolayout` or programatically define the centre of your pop up.

```
 myView.center = CGPoint(x: superView.center.x, y: superView.center.y)
```

Hope that helps.